# Re-use class to connect to second database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have sql connection manager to connect to my database like:

```
public class SQLConnMgr : Disposable {
    #region private properties
    SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection();
    private bool _Errors;

  private string
         _ErrMsg = string.Empty,
         _Catalog = string.Empty,
         _Server = string.Empty,
         _UserID = string.Empty,
         _Pwd = string.Empty,
         _ConnStr = string.Empty;
    public SQLConnMgr()
    {
        this.SetConnection();
        this.InitClass();
    }

    private void SetConnection()
    {
        AppSettingsReader reader = new AppSettingsReader();
        this._Server = (string)reader.GetValue("DBServer", this._Server.GetType());
        this._Catalog = (string)reader.GetValue("DBCatalog", this._Catalog.GetType());
        this._UserID = (string)reader.GetValue("DBUser", this._UserID.GetType());
        this._Pwd = (string)reader.GetValue("DBPwd", this._Pwd.GetType());
    }


   private void InitClass()
        {
            if (this._ConnStr == string.Empty)
            {
                System.Text.StringBuilder cn = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                cn.AppendFormat("Server={0};initial catalog={1};", this._Server, this._Catalog);
                cn.AppendFormat("user id={0};password={1};persist security info=True;packet size=4096;Connect Timeout=120", this._UserID, this._Pwd);
                dbconn.ConnectionString = cn.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                dbconn.ConnectionString = this._ConnStr;
            }
            try
            {
                // open connection to SQL
                dbconn.Open();
                if (dbconn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    this._Errors = true;
                    this._ErrMsg = "Connection State is not open!";
                }
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                this._ErrMsg = ex.Message;
                this._ErrMsg = string.Empty;
                //added 1/12/2010 - Johan
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(dbconn);
                SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
                // attempt the connection again?
                dbconn.Close();
                InitClass();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("Error occured while attempting connect to the database");
                sb.Append(e.Message.ToString());
                sb.Append(e.Source.ToString());
                sb.Append(e.TargetSite.ToString());
                this._ErrMsg = sb.ToString();
            }
        }
```

So when I want to use database I just call this class like this:

```
var db = new SQLConnMgr();
```

Then I can call methods inside this like:

```
db.GetTableBySQL($"exec usp_Reseller_Get");
```

My question is, how can I re-use this methods into another class to call another database, I mean, instead to use:

```
var db = new SQLConnMgr();
```

Now use `var bd = new SQLNewDatabaseConnMgr();`

To achieve that, I create another class and inherit `SQLConnMgr` into it like

```
public class SQLNewDatabaseConnMgr: SQLDataMgr
{

}
```

But now how can I call methods of my working class to set up new connection? Regards

**UPDATE**

As comment bellow I set `SetConnection()` method to protected virtual

```
 protected virtual void SetConnection()
        {
            AppSettingsReader reader = new AppSettingsReader();
            this._Server = (string)reader.GetValue("DBServer", this._Server.GetType());
            this._Catalog = (string)reader.GetValue("DBCatalog", this._Catalog.GetType());
            this._UserID = (string)reader.GetValue("DBUser", this._UserID.GetType());
            this._Pwd = (string)reader.GetValue("DBPwd", this._Pwd.GetType());
        }
```

Then in my new class I try

```
   public class SQLNewDatabaseConnMgr: SQLDataMgr
        {
            private string
             _ErrMsg = string.Empty,
             _Catalog = string.Empty,
             _Server = string.Empty,
             _UserID = string.Empty,
             _Pwd = string.Empty,
             _ConnStr = string.Empty;

            public override bool SetConnection()
            {
                AppSettingsReader reader = new AppSettingsReader();
                this._Server = (string)reader.GetValue("DBServer", this._Server.GetType());
                this._Catalog = (string)reader.GetValue("DBCatalog", this._Catalog.GetType());
                this._UserID = (string)reader.GetValue("DBUser", this._UserID.GetType());
                this._Pwd = (string)reader.GetValue("DBPwd", this._Pwd.GetType());
                return true;
            }
        }
```

But method return me error:

> 'SQLConnAllOrdersMgr.SetConnection()': no suitable method found to
>   override

Comment: You can make SetConnection() protected and virtual and override it on SQLNewDatabaseConnMgr to use different values. You will probably also need to override the _Server property.

Comment: See example in [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: How can I override it? I'm a little green in c#, can you give me fast example or documentation of how can I achieve it? @HubertJarema

Comment: Actually, you may want to lift some of your code into a common abstract base class, and then have two subclasses, one that mimics your current class, and a second for your new class.  That way, the only difference between the classes is a set of protected overridable properties specific to each class.  This is just a variation on what @HubertJarema suggested

Comment: By the way, I'm intrigued by this statement: `this._Server = (string)reader.GetValue("DBServer", this._Server.GetType());`.  The `_Server` property is calculated from the value of itself?

Comment: It getting values from app.config, and parameter it;s just an string let me update @Flydog57

Comment: @Flydog57 the AppSettingsReader, not db reader

Comment: As for the problem in your Update: you have to mark `SetConnection` as `virtual` in the base class.  Only virtual methods/properties can be overridden.

Comment: It's already a virtual class `protected virtual void SetConnection()`, but it still throw error @Flydog57

Comment: @djv's answer is what I was describing in my original comment.  Your problem is that you have `protected virtual **void** SetConnection` and `public override **bool** SetConnection`.  The signatures have to match

Comment: Look at connection strings as suggested by @OlivierJacot-Descombes . You could then pass the connection string key to your Constructor. You could even overload the constructor so that you only need to pass the key for any alternate DB connections to your default. Using the connection strings in a `.config` file also makes it pretty easy to encrypt your connection strings, which is something worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the properties which indicate the settings to use for the database connection. I think it's simpler than asking the developer to remember how to retrieve the settings (i.e. when marking `SetConnection` as virtual or abstract)

```
public abstract class SQLConnMgr : Disposable
{

    SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection();

    protected abstract string DBServer { get;  }
    protected abstract string DBCatalog { get;  }
    protected abstract string DBUser { get;  }
    protected abstract string DBPwd { get;  }

    protected string _Server;
    protected string _Catalog;
    protected string _UserID;
    protected string _Pwd;

    public SQLConnMgr()
    {
        this.SetConnection();
        this.InitClass();
    }

    protected void SetConnection()
    {
        AppSettingsReader reader = new AppSettingsReader();
        this._Server = (string)reader.GetValue(this.DBServer, this._Server.GetType());
        this._Catalog = (string)reader.GetValue(this.DBCatalog, this._Catalog.GetType());
        this._UserID = (string)reader.GetValue(this.DBUser, this._UserID.GetType());
        this._Pwd = (string)reader.GetValue(this.DBPwd, this._Pwd.GetType());
    }

}

public class SQLNewDatabaseConnMgr1 : SQLConnMgr
{
    protected override string DBServer => "DBServer1";
    protected override string DBCatalog => "DBCatalog1";
    protected override string DBUser => "DBUser1";
    protected override string DBPwd => "DBPwd1";
}

public class SQLNewDatabaseConnMgr2 : SQLConnMgr
{
    protected override string DBServer => "DBServer2";
    protected override string DBCatalog => "DBCatalog2";
    protected override string DBUser => "DBUser2";
    protected override string DBPwd => "DBPwd2";
}
```

Comment: And how can I call methods into my controllers now in my calls like:      `var db = new SQLConnMgr();` I'm getting: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'SQLConnMgr'

Comment: @jonathan right, well now you have two new classes so you would use `var db = new SQLNewDatabaseConnMgr1();`. Each of those derived classes can describe how to get the connection parameters in their override properties.